# Detect keypress off document

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm developing my own timer using electron and I would like to know if is possible to detect a keypress without the app in first plan. For example: I start the app, open another program, like discord and while I'm using discord, I can start the timer.

Comment: Might be able to start here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulled from Electron's documentation here:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut

> Detect keyboard events when the application does not have keyboard
> focus.

> The globalShortcut module can register/unregister a global keyboard
> shortcut with the operating system so that you can customize the
> operations for various shortcuts.
>
> Note: The shortcut is global; it will work even if the app does not
> have the keyboard focus. You should not use this module until the
> ready event of the app module is emitted.

```
const { app, globalShortcut } = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // Register a 'CommandOrControl+X' shortcut listener.
  const ret = globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', () => {
    console.log('CommandOrControl+X is pressed')
  })

  if (!ret) {
    console.log('registration failed')
  }

  // Check whether a shortcut is registered.
  console.log(globalShortcut.isRegistered('CommandOrControl+X'))
})

app.on('will-quit', () => {
  // Unregister a shortcut.
  globalShortcut.unregister('CommandOrControl+X')

  // Unregister all shortcuts.
  globalShortcut.unregisterAll()
})
```

Comment: That's very useful, thank you.
I already registered my keys, but my funtions are inside an external .js file, that .js file is being used in my html and I can't call those functions. I tried module.exports, but it doesn't work because I'm using "document.getElementById()" and it doesn't recognize.
How coul't I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it.
Thank you Nathan for showing me the way.

I added **executeJavaScript** and it works fine:

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const ret = globalShortcut.register('Z', () => {
      win.webContents.executeJavaScript("startContinue();");
  });
});
```